# SQL command will not insert into database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to use a VB button to insert data into a database, but it keeps bringing up the error message I have in place for exceptions.

Can anyone help me with why this does not update the database?

```
   Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim Customer As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Product As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim Location As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim Details As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim Owners As String = DropDownList1.Text
    Dim Urgency As String = DropDownList2.Text


    connetionString = "Data Source=ZUK55APP02;Initial Catalog=BugFixPortal;User ID=SLC***;Password=rep***"
    sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (Owner, Customer, Product, Location, Urgency, Details) VALUES ('" & Owners & ", " & Customer & ", " & Product & ", " & Location & ", " & Urgency & ", " & Details & "')"
    sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    Try
        sqlCnn.Open()
        adapter.UpdateCommand = sqlCnn.CreateCommand
        adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql
        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlCnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to update Database with Request - Please speak to Supervisor!")

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't spit out fixed text for a db exception. The exception should contain the exact error message. most like you've got an sql syntax error, due to being having a gaping wide open sql injection problem.

Comment: Apparently you're still enough of a newbie to concatenate strings straight from user-enterable fields.  You're vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2):

I would not go down this road as your code is weak against SQL Injection

you should use parameters instead.Something like the below

```
c.Open();
string insertString = @"insert into YourTable(name, street, city,....) values(@par1,  @par2, @parN,....)"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(insertString, c);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@par1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "MyName";
//etc
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
c.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly quoting your values.

This string has an opening and closing single quote around ALL the values, which is incorrect.

```
VALUES ('" & Owners & ", " & Customer & ", " & Product & ", " & Location & ", " & Urgency & ", " & Details & "')"
```

Instead, put single quotes around character data, eg., if `Product` is a varchar, it would look like this:

```
VALUES (" & Owners & ", " & Customer & ", '" & Product & "', " & Location & ", " & Urgency & ", " & Details & ")"
```

**The *real* problem, though, is that you should be using parameterized queries instead. This code is prone to SQL injection attacks.**

Answer (score 1):

Change this;

```
MsgBox("Unable to update Database with Request - Please speak to Supervisor!")
```

to Something like this;

```
MsgBox("Unable to update Database with Request - Please speak to Supervisor!" & ex.Message)
```

It will give you more details on the exception, however at a quick glance I can see a problem, the values you are trying to insert are strings, you've enclosed all your values in a single set of ' characters, rather than enclosing each string parameter in a pair of ' values, i.e.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (Owner, Customer, Product, Location, Urgency, Details) VALUES ('" & Owners & "', '" & Customer & "', '" & Product & "',' " & Location & "', '" & Urgency & "', '" & Details & "')"
```

Answer (score 1):

**You really should look at parameterizing your queries as you're wide open to SQL injection attacks. See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)**

In terms of your code itself, your SQL syntax is wrong as you need to put apostrophes around each value. Try this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (Owner, Customer, Product, Location, Urgency, Details)
VALUES ('" & Owners & "', '" & Customer & "', '" & Product &
     "', '" & Location & "', '" & Urgency & "', '" & Details & "')"
```

Here's an example using Parameters

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Requests (Owner, Customer, Product, Location, Urgency, Details)
VALUES ('@Owners', '@Customer', '@Product', '@Location', '@Urgency', '@Details')"
```

Then add parameters like so:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owners", Owners)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer", Customer)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", Product)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Urgency", Urgency)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", Details)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `adapter.InsertCommand` instead of `adapter.UpdateCommand`

in

```
Try
    sqlCnn.Open()
    adapter.UpdateCommand = sqlCnn.CreateCommand //(adapter.InsertCommand)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql //(adapter.InsertCommand)
    adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() //(adapter.InsertCommand)
    sqlCnn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Unable to update Database with Request - Please speak to Supervisor!")

End Try
```

and agree with parametrized sql query

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx for more infos